# OneDrive App Access Token

Tags: access-token, onedrive

Does anyone know how to get the *app* access token to a One-Drive API app?

I've tried combining {appId}|{appSecret} as the access_token param and as the Authorization header but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add the code you're using and the request/response details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OneDrive API docs have a good section on [getting auth tokens with OAuth](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm). In a nutshell, there are two services involved -- the OneDrive API service and the authentication service. The OneDrive API only accepts OAuth tokens that were issued by the authentication service. The authentication service is what you talk to first to get an auth token.

Depending on your app, you can either use the [token flow](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#token-flow) or the [code flow](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#code-flow) to get an auth token. In the 'token' flow, you navigate the user's browser to the authentication endpoint with your appId. The user may need to log in, consent, etc., and then the authentication endpoint redirects back to your site with an auth token you can use. The 'code' flow is similar to the 'token' flow, except it redirects back with an authentication code that your client app can use (along with its client secret) to obtain an auth token and a refresh token. Once you have a refresh token, you can use that to obtain future auth tokens without the user's involvement (as long as they granted the wl.offline_access scope).

Comment: How to get the token. I launched the access token url in browser then what? how will i get the access token??